# Erro ao tentar acionar o Share do Facebook em android SDK

Tags: java, android, facebook

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo android onde a pessoa poderá logar pelo Facebook.

Estou tentando desenvolver a opção "share" para que uma mensagem do aplicativo possa ser postada na linha do tempo do usuário, mas estou me deparando com o seguinte erro:

```
Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request
```

Acredito que o erro esteja no momento em que tento pedir a permissão de publicação para o usuário. Segue o código abaixo, aonde são feitas a autenticação e o processo de share do facebook:

**Activity principal**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private MainFragment mainFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
            mainFragment = new MainFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
            .commit();
        } else {
            // Or set the fragment from restored state info
            mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment{

    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    private Button shareButton;

    private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
    private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";
    private boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        shareButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
        LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        authButton.setFragment(this);
        authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_likes", "user_status"));
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = 
                savedInstanceState.getBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, false);
        }

        shareButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
        shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                publishStory();        
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            shareButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (pendingPublishReauthorization && 
                    state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)) {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
                publishStory();
            }
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            shareButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
        // session is not null, the session state change notification
        // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null &&
               (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }

        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, pendingPublishReauthorization);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private void publishStory() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session != null){

            // Check for publish permissions    
            List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
            if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                        .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                return;
            }

            Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
            postParams.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
            postParams.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
            postParams.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");

            Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                               .getGraphObject()
                                               .getInnerJSONObject();
                    String postId = null;
                    try {
                        postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.i(TAG,
                            "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
                    }
                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    if (error != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity()
                             .getApplicationContext(),
                             error.getErrorMessage(),
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity()
                                 .getApplicationContext(), 
                                 postId,
                                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            };

            Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, 
                                  HttpMethod.POST, callback);

            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();
        }

    }

    private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
        for (String string : subset) {
            if (!superset.contains(string)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**XML da activity**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shareButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Share"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Os LogCat retorna:

```
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.facebook.Session.requestNewPermissions(Session.java:1245)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.facebook.Session.requestNewPublishPermissions(Session.java:592)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.example.facebooksharedemo.MainFragment.publishStory(MainFragment.java:146)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.example.facebooksharedemo.MainFragment.onSessionStateChange(MainFragment.java:79)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.example.facebooksharedemo.MainFragment.access$0(MainFragment.java:73)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.example.facebooksharedemo.MainFragment$1.call(MainFragment.java:89)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.facebook.Session$4$1.run(Session.java:1542)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-08 16:07:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

O Login é efetuado com sucesso, mas quando clico no "share", a aplicação não requisita as novas permissões, dizendo apenas que eu já autorizei o app, e ele apresenta o erro.

Pelo que eu entendi. Ele não está adicionando a permissão de publicação e está fazendo a mesma request denovo, resultando no erro.

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: tente criar um [exemplo minimo e completo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) pois facilitaria para que outras pessoas te ajudem.

Comment: Pronto. Criei um novo projeto e coloquei apenas o processo de autenticação no facebook e o share.

Comment: Pesquisando sobre as permissões, parece que a `publish_actions` não é adequada para compartilhar conteúdo  dessa forma. Na lista de `permissions` (apesar de ser fql, acho que atende) existe uma `share_item` que parece ser mais adequada para seu caso, vê se resolve o problema. De uma olhada também em https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions/

Comment: O problema permanece o mesmo. Quando clico em "share", ele apenas diz que eu já autorizei o app. Olhando nas permissões da session mostra que ela não foi adicionada.

Comment: Pelo que vi, o seu authButton usa permissões diferentes (`authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_likes", "user_status"));`) da que está usando no Request (`Arrays.asList("publish_actions")`). É isso mesmo?

Comment: Sim. A APK do facebook não permite que eu coloque permissões de publicação no ato do login. Por isso os próprios exemplos da api do Facebook usam o `Session.NewPermissionsRequest`. Só que ele não está adicionando a nova permissão.

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: Não achei. Infelizmente